# Combine 2 Arrays In C Special Case

Tags: c, arrays

I need to combine two arrays in C. But the problem is I need a little different type of combining. I have two arrays. Firts one has 27 integers in it and second one has 9 integers.

```
int *firstArray = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32}
int *secondArray = {10,11,12,22,23,24,33,34,35}
int *newArray = malloc(36*sizeof(int));
```

I want to get newArray as integer array of numbers from 1 to 35. How can I combine these two arrays? Numbers are just for representing. I think for every 9k th element of first array I should add first second third ... 3 element of second array. But I could not code it.

Comment: What prevents you from coding it? If you answer "No idea how to start." then start with a HelloWorld. Then add your three "arrays" (you do know of course that above does not contain any arrays). Then write a function to output the target array. Then write a function to fill it, and output it. Maybe start by copying the longer array. Can you do that? Then show your code.

Comment: Try to go through the arrays with your fingers and see how you would pick elements. Basic idea is to have two indexes, `i` and `j`, so that if `firstArray[i] < secondArray[j]` you will take the first value and increment `i`, otherwise take the second value and increment `j` (unless any of the indices reaches the end of its array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, the issue here is in `firstArray`, you have a group of 9 numbers (1-9), another group of 9 numbers (13-21) and then a group of 8 numbers (25-32), so I had to account for that in the code. You can use nested loops to achieve what you want.

The idea is you read 9 from the first array, then 3 from the second array, until you are done (three times total) except in the last case, where you only read 8 from the first array.

```
   int i, j;
   for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
      for(j = 0; j < 9; j++){
         if(i == 2 && j == 8) break;
         newArray[(i * 12) + j] = firstArray[(i * 9) + j];
      }
      for(j = 0; j < 3; j++){
         if(i == 2)
            newArray[(i * 12) + 8 + j] = secondArray[(i * 3) + j];
         else
            newArray[(i * 12) + 9 + j] = secondArray[(i * 3) + j];
      }
   }
```

Comment: That is great. Thank you so much.

Comment: @ZopcukApp because your array "slices" have different lengths, I would consider the solution Groo suggested, assuming that the numbers are always in order. This will work even if the numbers aren't in order, but is a bit uglier code.